# Phrasal verb - go off

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As you know, the phrasal verb **to go off** has different meanings, depending on the context. I am particularly interested in whether it is okay to use it with this meaning:

> to begin to dislike somebody or something.

For example:

1. I **went off** men after my husband left me.
2. I **went off** the idea of buying a sports car after I found out how much it would cost.

Comment: I don`t understand the reason for down-voting my question. The vast majority of the members of this English language community are non-native speakers, trying to master their English language skills by asking questions here and receiving clear -cut answers. If you are not intelligent enough or unable to answer the question, just move on. Nobody wants your negativity here.

Comment: The answer is yes, you have used it correctly for the meaning you have provided. (Just a minor point which may  interest you: if you add "on" to it, to go off on [someone], it means to get angry with the person and shout at him/her.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for tour reply. I just wanted to know, whether how often do native speakers use this phrasal verb in the context given in my headline comment ?

Comment: It is very common in BrE.  It isn't really an AmE idiom.

Comment: Hello, Gio. Are you aware that there are regulations regarding the standard of questions and answers considered acceptable on ELU? In particular, the sister site ELL was established to address more basic questions (ELU being thereby reserved for more searching questions). Though there too, I believe that they require reasonable research to accompany questions. Close-voting and downvoting questions are the accepted ways that users here register their opinions that a question does not meet the normal requirements of the site, not a sign of lack of intelligence or negativity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  There are thousands of questions which are not suitable for this web-site here. Do I have to down-vote all of them now ? Whom this web-site was created for in the first place ? English language professionals or English language learners  ? By the way, I don`t think that my question was somehow basic. For us, non-native learners of English, it`s essential to know what`s the meaning of an idiom or phrasal verb, it is used in everyday speech or not, it is outdated it not, etc. We all are here to  broaden our intellectual horizons and help each other to grow.

Comment: You're essentially undermining the aims of ELU. There are _many_ other websites aimed at helping learners. ELU is perhaps the only one of its kind aimed at linguists. Would you turn up at the University of Birmingham claiming that they should help you improve your language proficiency?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The funny thing is that, the vast majority of the members of this community aren`t even native speakers, let alone linguists. As it seems, you don`t clearly understand what the aim of ELU is.Why do people ask questions here ? Just like that ? For fun ? Tell me.

Comment: Your question has been moved to ELL. I didn't (and in fact am unable to) do this. Please now realise that this sort of question is not appropriate on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is this question appropriate for ELU - Pronunciation of noun “expertise” ?  What about this - usage of not in negative sentences ?

Comment: (1) Not as it stands; no research is given. And I shouldn't think that dictionaries license the questioner's suggestion. / (2) Yes. The distribution of 'not' is difficult to explain, and the questioner's examples show a wide range of usages. Note Professor Lawler's answer there. // If you're about to complain that I didn't close-vote the pronunciation question, don't. Policing ELU is a job for all contributors, and I do far more than the average amount.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So, in your understanding, putting the negative particle "not" in a sentence is somehow difficult to explain ? I think, even 7th graders would tackle this type of question with ease, let alone linguists. No, I`m not going to complain about anything. I just wanted to note that there are thousands of questions on this web-site, not suitable to be discussed or even looked at.

Comment: 7th graders? Why is "I saw not a single person" idiomatic when "I have not a ten pound note" is not? Do _you_ know?

Answer (score 1):

As an idiom, it appears it would be alright to use in your context because "to go off" can mean "to sour or spoil".  But given the wide range of meanings that could be inferred from "go off", it might not be commonly used.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+sour

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is one of the meanings of the phrasal verb. Your second example is even mentioned as an example by [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-off#go-off__5).

They give the following definition (among many others):

> **[go off someone/something]** BRITISH to stop liking someone or something

Attribution: "Go Off - definition and Synonyms." Go off (phrasal Verb) Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary. Accessed April 15, 2018. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-off#go-off__5.